# Error Message in R using data frames

Tags: r, dataframe

I created a data frame called weather.info with the months as rows and the columns as `Monthly_Avg`, `DailyMax_Avg`, `DailyMin_Avg`, etc. The question is to show all rows of the data frame whose `DailyMax_Avg` is greater than 50. This is what I typed in:

```
subset(weather.info, DailyMax_Avg > 50)
```

But I'm getting an error that:

```
   Warning message:
In Ops.factor(DailyMax_Avg, 50) : ‘>’ not meaningful for factors
```

Can someone help me on how to fix this? I'm very new to R and is the first time working with the R language. Thanks!

Comment: The error message tells you the problem. The variable is not numeric. Since you expect it to be numeric, you should check why it isn't.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Convert `DailyMax_Avg` to numeric first:

```
weather.info$DailyMax_Avg <- as.numeric(as.character(weather.info$DailyMax_Avg))
```

Comment: I tried that and the error message is gone but not getting any output. This is what it says:  <0 rows> (or 0-length row.names). I did typeof(weather.info) and says its a list

Comment: @VRam can you please edit your question and provide the output of `dput(head(weather.info))`

Comment: Shouldn't it be `as.numeric(as.character(weather.info$DailyMax_Avg))`?

Comment: @VRam If it works you should mark one of the two answers as accepted, so that in the future others with the same issue can find a solution.

Answer (score 1):

You need to convert `DailyMax_Avg` to numeric before using `subset`. You can do

```
weather.info$DailyMax_Avg <- as.numeric(levels(weather.info$DailyMax_Avg))[weather.info$DailyMax_Avg]
```

Note that
`as.numeric(levels(weather.info$DailyMax_Avg))[weather.info$DailyMax_Avg]` is recommended (and more efficient than `as.numeric(as.character(weather.info$DailyMax_Avg))`) to convert factor to numeric. For more details see `?factor` (Warning section)